# Controls in page outside UserControl not updating on PreRender

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

Here is my code:

```
<asp:Label ID="myLabel" runat="server" Text="first label"></asp:Label>

<uc:myControl ID="myControl" runat="server" /> //contains a checkbox
```

---

myControl.ascx.cs

```
 public bool changeLabel { get; set; }

 protected void checkbox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  changeLabel = ((CheckBox) sender).Checked ? true : false;
 }
```

---

myPage.aspx.cs

```
    protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            myLabel.Text = myControl.changeLabel == true ? "second label" : "first label";
        }
    }
```

---

In debug mode, i can see my new value "second label" but it's not rendering in the page. Any advice ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't set the value on post-back in pre-render, because after this event the page applies the ViewState to the control, changing its value.  So you are setting it too early.  A better idea would be the Page Load event.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            myLabel.Text = myControl.changeLabel == true ? "second label" : "first label";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Page_Load event occurs before Pre_Render and before UserControl's Page_Load, so it doesn't make sense to me to assign the value in Page_Load

Comment: @Med That's my mistake man, I read that as Page_Init instead instead of Pre_Render, sorry about that!

Answer (score 0):

Try doing soemthing like this :

```
protected void checkbox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      Label l = (Label)this.Page.FindControl("myLabel");
      if (l != null && checkbox is checked)
      {
          l.Text = "second label";
      }
      else
     {
          l.Text = "first label";
     }
 }
```

:)